# Demonstrate a certain inequality related to the accompanying law theorem.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, weak-convergence

Suppose I have a triangular array of r.v. $(X_{nj})_{1\leq j \leq k_n}$- $X_{nj} \sim \mu_{nj}$, $k_n \uparrow\infty$ - which are independent in each row and satisfies the uniformly asymptotically negligible (u.a.n.) property:
$$\max_{1\leq j \leq k_n}P[ |X_{nj}| \geq \epsilon ] \to 0, \quad (n \to \infty)$$
Let $a_{nj} := \int_{|x|\leq 1}x d\mu_{nj}$ and $\tilde{X}_{nj} := X_{nj} - a_{nj}$. Define $\tilde{Y}_{nj}$, the  [compound poisson random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_Poisson_distribution), as
$$\tilde{Y}_{nj} = \sum_{\iota=1}^N \tilde{X}_{nj,\iota},\quad N\sim Poisson(1),\quad \tilde{X}_{nj,1}, \tilde{X}_{nj,2}, ... \hbox{copies of } \tilde{X}_{nj} $$

The Accompanying Laws Theorem says that for a certain sequence of real numbers $(A_n)$ and for a som random variable $L$, we have that:
$$\sum_{j=1}^{k_n} \tilde{X}_{nj} - A_n \to L \iff \sum_{j=1}^{k_n} \tilde{Y}_{nj} - A_n \to L $$
In fact, the real interest of this theorem is the version without tilde. I.e,
$$\sum_{j=1}^{k_n} X_{nj} - A_n \to L \iff \sum_{j=1}^{k_n} Y_{nj} - A_n \to L $$
But the crucial point that forces us to work with the tilde version is that we need the following fact: Let $\tilde{a}_{nj}:=\int_{|\tilde{X}_{nj}|\leq 1} x d\tilde{\mu}_{nj}$ where $\tilde{X}_{nj} \sim\tilde{\mu}_{nj}$. Then:
$$\exists\, C_0 < \infty, \quad |\tilde{a}_{nj}|\leq C_0\, P[|\tilde{X}_{nj}|\geq 1/2] $$
The fact is that this is not always true for $a_{nj}$ and $X_{nj}$. Furthermore, we would need this inequality in an attempt to prove the version without tilde.

However, I believe this to be true when
$$Var(\sum_{j=1}^{k_n} X_{nj} )= \sum_{j=1}^{k_n} Var(X_{nj})  \leq C, \quad \forall \, n\geq 1$$
which implies that $Var(X_{nj}) = \int x^2 d \mu_{nj}\leq C, \,\, \forall \, n,j\geq 1.$

I really wish this were true and I'm trying to prove it. First, it is worth mentioning that it is possible to show that $a_{nj}$ also satisfies u.a.n.:
\begin{equation}
    \lim_{n \to \infty} \max_{1\leq j \leq k_n } |a_{nj}| = 0.
\end{equation}
My attempt is to try to manipulate $|a_{nj}|\leq C_0\, P[|X_{nj}|\geq 1/2]$. Note that it implies $|a_{nj}|\leq C_0\,( 1 - P[|X_{nj}|< 1/2])$. Then, it is equivalent to:
$$\int_{|X_{nj}|< 1/2} (x+C_0) \, d \mu_{nj} + \int_{1/2\leq |X_{nj}|\leq 1} x\, d \mu_{nj} \leq C_0$$

But I don't know if I can conclude using the uniform limitation of variances.
Helps!